# How to set refresh token in API routes in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, proxy, refresh-token

I am building the profile update feature with refresh token and I forward calls to the API through an API Route with a proxy middleware in Next.js:

**Client** --> **update profile request** --> **API Routes** (implement proxy middleware to forward requests to API server) --> **API server** (send back to API Routes with response refresh token) --> **Set refresh token in API Routes**

Above is my expected road map, I want to set refresh token from API server in **API Routes** when the refresh token contained in response data but I don't know how to access to the response data in API Routes to get refresh token and set it to cookie. How can I do it?

Here my code:

*/pages/api/[...path].js*  (API Routes)

```
import httpProxyMiddleware from 'next-http-proxy-middleware';

export const config = {
    api: {
        // Enable `externalResolver` option in Next.js
        externalResolver: true,
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

const handler = async (req, res) => {

    // I want access to response data in `res` variable to get refresh token and set it to cookie

    const cookie = parseCookies({ req });
    if (req.headers.cookie && cookie) {
        req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${cookie['access_token']}`;
    }

    httpProxyMiddleware(req, res, {
        target: 'http://api.my-server-api.com',
        ws: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        selfHandleResponse: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        headers: {
            cookie: '', // remove cookie value
        },
    });
};

export default handler;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle your own response after receiving the proxyRes, you can do so with selfHandleResponse. As you can see below, if you use this option, you are able to intercept and read the proxyRes but you must also make sure to reply to the res itself otherwise the original client will never receive any data.

Code:

```
const handleProxyInit = (proxy) => {
    proxy.on('proxyRes', (proxyRes, req, res) => {
        let body = [];
        proxyRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body.push(chunk);
        });
        proxyRes.on('end', function () {
            body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
            console.log('res from proxied server:', JSON.parse(body));
            res.end('my response to cli');
        });
    });
};

httpProxyMiddleware(req, res, {
    // You can use the `http-proxy` option
    target: process.env.SERVER_HOST,
    ws: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    selfHandleResponse: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    headers: {
        cookie: '', // remove cookie value
    },
    onProxyInit: handleProxyInit,
});
```

Hope it helped!